# jQuery how to disable event handle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this:

```
<li id='#myElement'>
    <a href="#">Click here</a>
</li>

$('#myElement').on("click", function() {
    alert('Hello world');
});
```

How i can disable and enable it i try three methods:

```
$('#myElement').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#myElement').css('pointer-evenet', 'none');
$('#myElement').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Looks like a multiple choice from a homework...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove hash from `<li id='#myElement'>`. Correct syntax is :

```
<li id='myElement'>

$('#myElement').on("click", function() {...
```

Then

```
$('#myElement').off("click")
// or
$('#myElement').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

will both work (but not `'pointer-evenet'`)...

**Demonstration :**

```js
$('#myElement').on("click", function() {
    alert('Hello world');
});

$('#myElement').css('pointer-events', 'none');

// or : 
// $('#myElement').off("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id='myElement'>
    <a href="#">Click here</a> (nothing should happen)
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li id='#myElement'> <a href="#">Click here</a></li>

function click_on() {
    $('#myElement').on("click", function () {
        alert('Hello world');
    });
}

click_on();
```

When you want to off:

```
$('#myElement').off()
```

When you want to on:

```
click_on();
```

Comment: Bad idea a lot redrawing in big source code.. because a lot of trigger click on touch events..